# How to know forgotten port?

Tags: php

For host I can ping it. but I forgot port. how can I know which port is it?

```
$host[] = '117.111.158.245'; $comment[]="Microsoft Windows Server 2008";  $port[] = '';
```

Comment: use some tool like nmap

Comment: ?? to which protocol you are calling? http/ftp/rmtp/ssh ?